# why a contract alway is itself interface? like（contract Wolf is IWolf; contract Lostpoets is ILostpoets ）

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I can understand the reason of why there is a IERC721, because it's standard.

BUT I can not understand why lots of project's contract is itself's interface, like

contract Woolf is IWoolf {}
contract Lostpoets is Ilostpoets {}

Can't they just write in one contract?

Answer (score 0):

dApps can use interfaces for the same reasons as standards – they have methods that need to be used throughout their project. Because methods in an [interface](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#interfaces) must be implemented in any contract that inherits it, they are used like a template. Maybe their project is upgradeable or can be extended with other contracts. Interfaces facilitate this kind of extensibility.

Edit: Here's an [article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-all-about-interfaces-f547d2869499) that goes more in-depth on the use of interfaces. Particularly, this point:

> Knowing that a smart contract is based on a specific interface makes it easy [to] understand what the contract can do, and
> know how to interact with the contract.
> It removes the need of understanding the complexity behind the actual functions themselves.

Comment: I thought this was an interesting question and made a [video with a short explanation](https://www.tiktok.com/@larissa_dev/video/7093559395258207494)